# How to Let Facebook Share Recognise Random Background Image

Tags: php, facebook, random, background-image, share

my problem is, I am generating my background images per CSS and PHP on my web site http://goo.gl/VDtmbk like this:

CSS:

```
background: url(random_img.php) no-repeat top left fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover; 
background-attachment: fixed;
```

PHP, random_img.php:

```
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$vorresult = glob( "../../uploads/*1500x*.jpg" );
$result = array_diff( $vorresult, glob( "../../uploads/*{person,karte}*.jpg", GLOB_BRACE ) );
$seed = floor(time()/120); 
srand($seed); 
$random_image = $result[rand(0, count($result)-1)];
header('Location:'.$random_image.'');
```

I read somewhere: Facebook should find images on one's web site with no problem, as long as they appear directly in the html (as `<img src="path/to/img.png" />`) and not via css (`background-image: url(path/to/img.png);`).

So, is there a way to solve this, so Facebook Sharing "sees" the random background image (to have it then in the shared post on FB)?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it would bring many issues to you. However, assuming it should work (which I'm most likely thinking no), what you could do is with generate the FB og:image metatag dynamically (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters)

I'm not 100% sure this would work because if your website is popular, I doubt Facebook will change the image every time it's generated. I am 100% sure it will freeze the title after a certain number of shares.

Comment: If you update the image/post you need to rerun the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) tool to clear facebook's cache. This could be achieved dynamic as well with a `cURL` request of sorts